# Find out children of a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains a set of label and div.  I want to obtain id of each div.  I tried the following:

```
            $('#divAppHolder').children().each(function () {
            });
```

but that returns both label and div.

I tried:

```
            $('#divAppHolder').find(':div').each(function () {

            });
```

but the code did not execute.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$('#divAppHolder').find('div').each(function () {

});
```

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="childA">A</div>
    <div id="childB">B</div>
    <label id="badchild">-</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent").find('div').each(function() {
       alert($(this).attr('id')); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BMtnu/

See also: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
$('#divAppHolder').find('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $('#divAppHolder').find(':div').each(function () {});
```

By

```
$('#divAppHolder').find('div').each(function () {});
```